# Vue SFC - Webpack maybe not including style block

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I have webpack set up to process my single file Vue components, but it seems to ignore the `<style>` block. Here is my full config file:

```
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  watch: true,
  mode: 'development',
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname + '/src/webpack-entry.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/assets/'),
    filename: 'vue.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          { loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              additionalData: `
                @import "./src/scss/_variables.scss";
              `
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
  ]
};
```

The generated .js files work fine. They just don't have the scoped style. I want to say it's a webpack configuration problem as I'm not super versed in webpack configuration. Let me know if there is any context that needs to be added or described.

Comment: If you are using SFC then you should consider using Vue CLI which will automatically  provide a Webpack config for you (and you can customize this default config through `vue.config.js`)

Comment: Yep, got it working with Vue CLI/vue.config.js. Would have liked it to work without the black box, but I don't care to dig deeper at this point.

Comment: You can always try `vue inspect` (https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#inspecting-the-project-s-webpack-config) to see the real Webpack config and then probably reuse it without the "black" box. When I migrated from Vue CLI v2 to v3 initially I was a little annoyed but now I simply tweak here and there in `vue.config.js` and do not care about the rest.